# Is Web.config enough for a Windows Authentication on an MVC 4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been looking for days and all I can find to set the windows authentication on MVC4 is to add a line of code to the Web.config file

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Once I log in to my application, I can indeed see my user in the page and if I add restrictions to a view, the server will ask for different credentials. It works alright.

But what bugs me is that **I never entered any other sort of information** about any Active Directory server. I feel like there is still some missing configuration and I can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is all you need to do to enable Windows Authentication for ASP.NET.

The reason why this "just works" can be explained in [this great document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx) (oldie but a goodie): (copy/pasted for direct reference)

> When ASP.NET is configured for Windows authentication, it relies on IIS to authenticate its clients using the configured authentication mode. IIS determines the authentication mode for a particular application by examining its metabase settings. After successfully authenticating a user, IIS passes the Windows token representing the authenticated user to the ASP.NET worker process (w3wp.exe) in which the ASP.NET application is hosted. If your application uses a virtual directory that is configured in IIS to support anonymous access, the token represents the anonymous Internet user account; otherwise, the token represents the authenticated user.